# Build gradle project inside a Docker

Tags: docker, gradle, build.gradle, file-permissions

I have a simple gradle project which I want to build inside the Docker container

I have a multistage docker build. The first stage just clone the project from github. The second stage must build the project so I can run it in the final stage. But it fails on in

```
FROM gradle:4.2.1-jdk8-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=0 /app/myProject /app
RUN ./gradlew build --stacktrace
```

The command `./gradlew build --stacktrace` cannot be executed and fails with the error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not update /app/.gradle/3.5-rc-2/file-changes/last-build.bin
```

And the stacktrace:

```
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not update /app/.gradle/3.5-rc-2/file-changes/last-build.bin
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.FileTimeStampInspector.updateOnFinishBuild(FileTimeStampInspector.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.BuildScopeFileTimeStampInspector.stop(BuildScopeFileTimeStampInspector.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.CompositeStoppable.stop(CompositeStoppable.java:98)
.....
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app/.gradle/3.5-rc-2/file-changes/last-build.bin (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
......
```

Why the docker user doesn't have permission to create a file in the working directory and how to add these permissions?
Simple `RUN chmod 777 /app` doesn't work and tells me: `chmod: /app: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Have a look at the docker file for gradle:4.2.1-jdk8-alpine https://github.com/keeganwitt/docker-gradle/blob/2d38bdd0ca754b0ee54ad29a483778fd84bfcbe4/jdk8-alpine/Dockerfile. It sets USER "gradle". The files that you are copying from your app directory to docker image's app directory may not have right permissions for "gradle" user. Now RUN chmod is not working because that command is being run as again "gradle" user inside docker context. So, you have to run "chown -R nobody:nobody /path/to/app/myProject" on your local terminal and then build the docker image.

Comment: @Cyclops thanks for the comment. What do you mean by local terminal? Can't I automate it in my Dockerfile?

Comment: You can add following 3 commands in your dockerfile:
--------
1. USER root # This changes default user to root
2. RUN chown -R gradle /app # This changes ownership of folder
3. USER gradle # This changes the user back to the default user "gradle"

Comment: Forgot to add one more thing. These 3 lines will go below the COPY command in your docker file. Let me know if this works for you. I've faced similar kind of issues in the past regarding files and folders ownership issues. I've resolved them in similar way.

Comment: @Cyclops it's working. Post it as an answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/keeganwitt/docker-gradle/blob/2d38bdd0ca754b0ee54ad29a483778fd84bfcbe4/jdk8-alpine/Dockerfile) for gradle:4.2.1-jdk8-alpine at , it has "[gradle](https://github.com/keeganwitt/docker-gradle/blob/2d38bdd0ca754b0ee54ad29a483778fd84bfcbe4/jdk8-alpine/Dockerfile#L41)" as its default user. The files that you are copying from your app directory to docker image's app directory may not have right permissions for "gradle" user.

You should add three additional commands in your Dockerfile for setting the correct permissions:

```
FROM gradle:4.2.1-jdk8-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=0 /app/myProject /app

USER root                # This changes default user to root
RUN chown -R gradle /app # This changes ownership of folder
USER gradle              # This changes the user back to the default user "gradle"

RUN ./gradlew build --stacktrace
```

Answer (score 9):

Another option could be to use the `ADD` command instead of `COPY` and then use it's `--chown` option to change the owner of the file after copy. So the final Dockerfile would be even simpler.

```
FROM gradle:4.2.1-jdk8-alpine
WORKDIR /app
ADD --chown=gradle:gradle /app/myProject /app

RUN ./gradlew build --stacktrace
```

Comment: COPY also supports the `--chown` option, see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy